# Sending octet stream via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I send an octet-stream via ajax to my PHP server. I want to receive it as the octet stream and decode it, not as a string. The thing is that the request body is a string, and it seems that ajax sends it as plain text, even though I have overriden the mime type. This is my ajax:

```
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
            if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
                console.log(xmlhttp);
            }
            else if(xmlhttp.status == 400) {
                alert('There was an error 400')
            }
            else {
                alert('something else other than 200 was returned')
            }
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "something.php", true);
    xmlhttp.overrideMimeType("application/octet-stream");
    xmlhttp.send(stream); // some array buffer
```

The request headers:

```
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:80
Response Headers
view source
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:175
Content-Type:application/octet-stream
Date:Sat, 30 Apr 2016 17:07:04 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
Server:Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.4
X-Powered-By:PHP/7.0.4
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:160
Request Payload
@9a54dbc4bdd16c1a19804751d113c44b@Some very boring string here :)
```

So the mime type is `octet-stream`, but the request payload is a string. What's wrong?

Comment: Would you be able to post PHP code? The request payload could very well be just binary output streamed to the console or whatever.

Comment: What's wrong is that Ajax isn't a web-browser, but simply a javascript request for data.... web browsers have built-in rules that determine how they should handle the response headers when a page is accessed, but ajax calls don't know what to do with the headers or the data stream unless you explicitly code it in javascript

Comment: Remove the `overrideMimeType` and use `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')` instead

Comment: `header('Content-type: application/octet-stream'); $body = file_get_contents('php://input'); print_r($body);` - that's the only PHP content

Comment: I tried var_dumping it, echoing it, checking the type, it all gives me plain string.

Comment: Changing the mime-type to `application/octect-stream` doesn't make the contents binary. 
I can't tell what `stream` (_some array buffer_) is exactly in your code, so [here's a link on how to work with binary data in ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data).
In short, you will need to work with [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) and/or [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob).